# Func parameter in LINQ expression

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have problem with Func delegate in LINQ expression. This is the problematic part of the method (repository.Items is `IQueryable<T>)` :

```
public static ActionResult XXX<T>(IRepository<T> repository,
        Func<T, int> keyExtractor, int id = 0)
    {
        if (id == 0) return ...
        T item = repository.Items.Where(x => keyExtractor(x) == id).
           FirstOrDefault();
        if (item == null) return ...
        try {
            repository.DeleteItem(item);
            return ...
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return ...
        }
    }
```

But when i run the method, i get error like type of node is not supported in LINQ entities. I tried also version with predikate but i had no luck at all.

Any ideas how to fix it?

I find out one possible way. LINQ performs delayed execution so i must first enforce execution like this:

`T item = repository.Items.AsEnumerable().Where(x => keyExtractor(x) == id)`

Comment: It would be nice to see the whole error text as well as the whole method.

Comment: Oh, i figured it out. LINQ expression must be executed first by AsEnumerable() method or something similiar:

Comment: Then you should post this as an answer and mark it as such. It will be helpful for others when they search for the same thing.

Comment: I think if the OP found the answer himself, he should delete the answer.

Comment: you mean delete the question? Actually I agree. This question would have been more helpful if it was obvious that `IRepository` is an `IQueryable`.

Comment: @KingKing Not as a rule, but in this case where the answer isn't particularly valuable content they should.

Comment: @user2712553 Do note that executing the LINQ query will, in fact, load all of the database table into memory. You can construct dynamic LINQ-to-Entities queries using [LINQKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx), but that requires restructing your code a fair bit. LINQKit works by pasting expression trees together, so you still can't call arbitrary C# code or client-side methods - all the parts need to be supported in LINQ-to-Entities in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to work on a `IQueryable<T>`, your argument must be an `Expression<Func<T, int>>`,  not a `Func<T, int>`.

`Func<T, int>` will work with an `IEnumerable<T>`.

`Where` extensions methods has the same name for `IQueryable<T>` and `IEnumerable<T>`, but not the same arguments...

(by the way you could write `repository.Items.FirstOrDefault(x => keyExtractor(x) == id)`;